# How do you call this iOS 7 control?

Tags: ios, controls

I am looking to add to my iOS app a control that looks like this menu on the bottom:

[image: http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/WhatsApp-iOS-7-uodate-image-002.jpg]

Can anybody tell me what control that is? Does not look like  Picker View.

Answer (score 4):

That is a `UIActionSheet`. [Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It cannot be dragged in from the list of UI elements.  It is presented programmatically very similar to a `UIAlertView`.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" 
    destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive Button" 
    otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button 1", @"Other Button 2", nil];

[actionSheet show];
```